# error: list index out of range during swap between list

Tags: python

Hi i have run this code and it work for the first 2 list but it got error the third list, here is the code:

```
    b = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
    c = [1, 1, 2]

    for i, item in enumerate(c):
        target_i = (i + 1) % 3
        temp = b[i][item]
        b[i][item] = b[target_i][item]
        b[target_i][item] = temp
        print(b)
```

and this is the output:

```
    [[1, 4], [3, 2], [5, 6]]
    [[1, 4], [3, 6], [5, 2]]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python34/LEARN/play/dapatkan_index2.py", line 7, in <module>
    temp = b[i][item]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add a check before and see if the iterating value lies below the length of the list b. You should do something like this

```
 for i, item in enumerate(c):
    if i < len(b):
       if item < len(b[i]):
          <your code>

    else : 
       pass
```

If the value of either i ( list index of c) or the value of c[i] is greater that the list indices, you would get this error. 
Here in the else statement I have just given a pass statement, but you must figure out what is required by the code and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `c` contains values in `1, 2`, the statement `b[i][item]` will index into `b[0][1]`, `b[0][2]`, .. etc. To fix, you probably intended `b[i][item - 1]`, or change the values in `c`.

Comment: I can't change the value of 'c' since it been generated from other function and by adding -1 to the 'item' it will change the position that need to be swaped

Comment: `item` is either `1` or `2`. Since each `b[i]` is a list of length two, indexing it with `2` (with happens in the third iteration) causes it to fail since you access the THIRD element in it.